# Finding average depth of filled sink using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, dem, raster-calculator, hydrology, sink

How to find out the depth of a filled cells (filled using "Fill" tool for a DEM)?

I have a DEM (50m resolution) for which I used "Fill" tool of the hydrology tool of ArcGIS Pro to fill up all the sinks; it returned me a filled DEM (all sinks were filled, no Z limit was used)

I used "Raster calculator" to perform: [dem_fill] - [dem] = it returned me all the sinks that were filled in the process

Now, how can I find out the average depth of those filled sink cells? Should weighted values of the filled cells be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the average of all your sinks then you could convert your difference raster to a point dataset. Each pixel would become a row in your point dataset. Delete out zero difference and summarize the rest. I am not sure why you would want to weight these values.